# Odoo attributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I'm trying to create a dependence between two fields. The `status` field and the `user_id` field. I have this issue with many states. What I want is that when the issue is confirmed the field `Assigned to` appears. Then when I assign the issue to someone, the state changes automatically from `Confirmed` to `Assigned`. So I created this python code:

```
class ProjectIssue(models.Model):
    _name = "project.issue"
    _description = "Project Issue"
    _inherit = "project.issue"

    state = fields.Selection([('new', 'New'),
                           ('feedback', 'Feedback'), 
                           ('acknowledged', 'Acknowledged'), 
                           ('confirmed', 'Confirmed'), 
                           ('assigned', 'Assigned'), 
                           ('testing', 'Testing'), 
                           ('resolved', 'Resolved'), 
                           ('closed', 'Closed'), 
                            ], string='Issue Status', default='new')

    def action_back_to_new(self):
        return self.write({'state': 'new'})
    def action_upgrade_to_feedback(self):
        return self.write({'state': 'feedback'})
    def action_back_to_feedback(self):
        return self.write({'state':'feedback'})
    def action_acknowledge(self):
        return self.write({'state':'acknowledged'})
    def action_confirm(self):
        return self.write({'state':'confirmed'})

    @api.onchange('user_id')
    def action_upgrade_to_assigned(self):
        return self.write({'state':'assigned'})
```

And this is the `xml` code:

```
    <record id="project_issue_form_view_2" model="ir.ui.view">
          <field name="name">project.issue.form</field>
          <field name="model">project.issue</field>
          <field name="inherit_id" ref="project_issue.project_issue_form_view"/>
          <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="stage_id" position="replace">
                <button name="action_confirm" string="Confirm" type="object" states="acknowledged" class="btn-primary"/>
                <button name="action_back_to_feedback" string="Back to Feedback" type="object" states="acknowledged" class="btn-primary"/>
                <button name="action_back_to_new" string="Back to new" type="object" states="feedback" class="btn-primary"/>
                <button name="action_acknowledge" string="Acknowledge" type="object" states="feedback" class="btn-primary"/>
                <button name="action_upgrade_to_feedback" string="Upgrade to feedback" type="object" states="new" class="btn-primary"/>
                <field name="state" widget="statusbar"/>
            </field>
            <field name="priority" position="replace">
                <field name="ipriority"/>
            </field>
            <field name="user_id" position="replace">
                <field name="user_id" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', 'in', ['new', 'feedback', 'acknowledged'])]}"/>
            </field>
          </field>
     </record>
    </field>
```

When I run this code and change `user_id` this error appears:

```
     File "C:\Users\PC\git\odoo\odoo-10.0\odoo\http.py", line 935, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
     File "C:\Users\PC\git\odoo\odoo-10.0\odoo\http.py", line 506, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
     File "C:\Users\PC\git\odoo\odoo-10.0\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 885, in call_kw
return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
     File "C:\Users\PC\git\odoo\odoo-10.0\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 877, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
     File "C:\Users\PC\git\odoo\odoo-10.0\odoo\api.py", line 689, in call_kw
return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
     File "C:\Users\PC\git\odoo\odoo-10.0\odoo\api.py", line 680, in call_kw_multi
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
     File "C:\Users\PC\git\odoo\odoo-10.0\odoo\models.py", line 5494, in onchange
record._onchange_eval(name, field_onchange[name], result)
     File "C:\Users\PC\git\odoo\odoo-10.0\odoo\models.py", line 5393, in _onchange_eval
process(method_res)
     File "C:\Users\PC\git\odoo\odoo-10.0\odoo\models.py", line 5370, in process
if res.get('value'):
    AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Remove return statement from the onchange method. that's it.

Comment: @VikiChavada I removed the return statement. there's no error anymore but user_id field became visible, there are no buttons in the header nor a default state.

Comment: it became visible because you added that domain. that you want this field invisible when state in ['new', 'feedback', 'acknowledged'] but in method you set the state in assigned. so, it visible.

Comment: actually the code doesn't show any state, no buttons, and in my code the default state is 'new'. so I have a problem with the hole header.

Comment: explain me what exactly you are trying to perform?

Comment: I'm trying to create a workflow for the issue record, in the view the header contains many buttons that switch between statuses. But to change the status of the issue from 'confirmed' to 'assigned'. The manager have to fill the field 'Assigned to' first. I created all the buttons and their methods. and to change the issue's state from confirmed to assigned. I need to check the 'user_id' field and see if it's filled. I hope this explains.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove return in def  action_upgrade_to_assigned

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the error is related to the onchange method.

**return self.write({'state':'assigned'})** => This process return a **boolean** result.

I had the same sitution when I was doing this:

```
    @api.onchange('date_to')
    def _onchange_date_to(self):
        date_from = self.date_from
        date_to = self.date_to
        if not (date_from or date_to):
            return True
```

The problem was solved by fixing **"return True"** as **"return"**.

Good Luck !

Answer (score 0):

The returned value of [onchange](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/odoo/api.py#L170) method is wrong because Odoo is expecting a dict and you return the result of write method which is a boolean.